# how could i use JPA criteria query api for joined columns?

Tags: jpa, foreign-key-relationship, criteria-api

i am new to JPA and i have a problem with it.

suppose that we have two tables which are related

by a ManytoOne association, which means that

table A stores a primary key of table B within it.

when these two tables are mapped to JPA entities

i have a problem for search on this situation.

i have used an existing code from richfaces demo, to handle filtering and sorting by using

JPA. this code is using input parameters to create criteria query.

this is the code:

```
private CriteriaQuery<T> createSelectCriteriaQuery() {
        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<T> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(entityClass);
        Root<T> root = criteriaQuery.from(entityClass);

        if (arrangeableState != null) {

            List<Order> orders = createOrders(criteriaBuilder, root);
            if (!orders.isEmpty()) {
                criteriaQuery.orderBy(orders);
            }

            Expression<Boolean> filterCriteria = createFilterCriteria(criteriaBuilder, root);
            if (filterCriteria != null) {
                criteriaQuery.where(filterCriteria);
            }
        }

        return criteriaQuery;
    }
    protected Expression<Boolean> createFilterCriteriaForField(String propertyName, Object filterValue, Root<T> root, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
        String stringFilterValue = (String) filterValue;
        if (Strings.isNullOrEmpty(stringFilterValue)) {
            return null;
        }

        stringFilterValue = stringFilterValue.toLowerCase(arrangeableState.getLocale());

        Path<String> expression = root.get(propertyName);
        Expression<Integer> locator = criteriaBuilder.locate(criteriaBuilder.lower(expression), stringFilterValue, 1);
        return criteriaBuilder.gt(locator, 0);
    }


    private Expression<Boolean> createFilterCriteria(CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder, Root<T> root) {
        Expression<Boolean> filterCriteria = null;
        List<FilterField> filterFields = arrangeableState.getFilterFields();
        if (filterFields != null && !filterFields.isEmpty()) {
            FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

            for (FilterField filterField : filterFields) {
                String propertyName = (String) filterField.getFilterExpression().getValue(facesContext.getELContext());
                Object filterValue = filterField.getFilterValue();

                Expression<Boolean> predicate = createFilterCriteriaForField(propertyName, filterValue, root, criteriaBuilder);

                if (predicate == null) {
                    continue;
                }

                if (filterCriteria == null) {
                    filterCriteria = predicate.as(Boolean.class);
                } else {
                    filterCriteria = criteriaBuilder.and(filterCriteria, predicate.as(Boolean.class));
                }
            }

        }
        return filterCriteria;
    }
```

the code is okay, when i try to filter columns(not joined columns), but when i try to

query on joined column, the produced query is not correct and it throws exception.

so my question is that, how could i use JPA criteria query api, to filter rows by both

joined columns and non-joined coulmns.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you can treat join columns like regular ones.

for example if you want to filter on id of B, you would have to create a join from A to B , then use B_.id  to match values.

Shay